# Tests still failing on TeamCity even after full rollback

Tags: tfs, teamcity, vstest

I use TeamCity 10.x (Enterprise), as well as TFS for source control.

I recently committed a changeset which did not break the build, but ended up causing hundreds of unit tests to fail across 10+ test projects. Those tests started failing immediately after my check-in, so naturally I assumed that I was at fault.

The changeset included these changes:

1. Changing the namespaces of various files (e.g., moving all test stubs to a "Stubs" folder and updating their namespace to end with the ".Stubs" suffix);
2. Updating the `using` statements in other files to reference these new namespaces where necessary;
3. Rewriting some unit tests using the Moq library, replacing TypeMock.

I rolled back the entire changeset, in the hopes that all the unit tests would pass again.

Unfortunately, most of the test projects continue to have a lot of failing tests. Additionally, these failing tests are causing all of the remaining tests to be skipped by the VS Test Engine. This is new behaviour that I hadn't seen before.

**Questions:**

1. Why are the tests still failing even though I have rolled back the offending changeset?
2. What can I do to fix this?

If I haven't provided enough information in this post, please let me know and I shall update.

Comment: You can try to clean the caches and  sources on agent, then try it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Check that if you indeed rollback the changeset.
- Check how TeamCity get the sources, get the latest changeset or
  specific changeset?
- Try to clean caches and pervious sources on agent machine（Clean all files before build）, then try it again.

  Reference : [Clean Checkout](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Clean+Checkout) and 
  [Clean Sources](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=61213169)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I didn't spend any more time on this last night because I was tired, but this morning all the test projects were green again. I believe it has something to do with how TeamCity gets its sources, because 1. I definitely committed a full rollback, and 2. by default, all build directories are cleaned before each build. So the reason must lie in the second point you mentioned.